# Android layout: align text to Imagebutton

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to build a simple layout, but I'm not able to complete a simple task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget43"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget42" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/widget42"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd like to have the Text on the right of the icon, centered vertically with the icon size. I saw that `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` is aligning the text on the upper side. I tried to change this with other properties, but I'm not able to obtain the result (I'm new to this, so forgive me if I'm missing something stupid).

So, I'd like to obtain:

----------

- ICON -       TEXT

----------

and not

----------       TEXT

- ICON -

----------

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:: It's useful to you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget43"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget42" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/widget42"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have added one line code in your TextView :

```
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

```
android:layout_alignBaseline for text:
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/widget42"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
RelativeLayout

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

and in

```
TextView
```

use

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

instead of

```
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to solve

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget43"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget42"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/widget42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```